# Where can I find the xml schema (xsd) that targets the Visual Studio Report Designer namespace

Tags: rdlc

The reason why I would need this is to create .rdlc files programmatically that could then be opened in Visual Studio Report Designer. I know the report definition xsd is readily available, but require the **report designer xsd** (denoted by the "rd" prefix, below)

This is from the root node of .rdlc files generated by Visual Studio Report Designer

```
 <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

In other words, I need an XSD that starts with

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" ... />
```

Does anyone know where to find such an XSD?

Comment: The bounty did not succeed. I don't think this file is currently available, so I created a uservoice item for it: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/15925384-provide-the-http-schemas-microsoft-com-sqlserve.

Answer (score 3):

I entered this URL in the address bar of the browser:
http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition

And it loaded a page with a link to the XSD
[image]

Clicked on the link and it opened the XSD file.

Comment: The ReportDefinition XSD is available, we are looking for the ReportDesigner XSD: `http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner`. I say "we" but I assume cyanos gave up a few years ago.

Comment: As far as I know the report definition file is not publicly available. However, if the goal is to create the reports programmatically, you should use RDL. MSDN has articles that explain the available data types and the RDL language references.

Comment: I'm already creating the RDL and RSD with the corresponding XSDs, I need to add the ReportDesigner part to provide its specific information, like you are doing when you design the report/dataset in Visual Studio or Report Builder.